# Starting ./manage.py runworker in the background

Tags: django, linux, django-channels

I wanted to know what my options are of starting

```
 ./manage.py runworker
```

in the background. I tried doing this

```
python ./manage.py runworker 2>>./daphneWorker.log >&2
```

but that does not seem to work either. Any suggestions on how I can make it run in the background ?

Comment: Try to add & at the end. Should end like that "... >&2 &". If you need this command to outlive your terminal session, you should also add "nohup python..." at the beggining

Comment: I was not familiar with nohup ill have to look into that

Comment: It still seems to be running in the foreground. It moves to the background but then comes to the foreground to print something when an event occurs

Comment: you can either do  `./manage.py runworker >> log.log 2>&1` or `nohup  ./manage.py runworker`

Comment: @JibinMathews I tried `./manage.py runworker >> log.log 2>&1` this time the outputs being logged but its not running in the background

Comment: You could also try running it as a systemd service, or via supervisor

Answer (score 5):

You can use `nohup` to keep it running in background.

```
nohup python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80 &
```

> **nohup** prevents the command from being aborted automatically when you
>   log out or exit the shell.

In order to stop the process running the server on port 80

```
netstat -nlp | grep :80
```

The above command gives you the processId or PID

Then:

```
kill PID
```

And in case you would like to log output

```
nohup python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80 > myLog.out &
```

Comment: No. I meant runserver. But, what is runworker here?

Answer (score 3):

I always use `screen` tool for this kind of jobs. It is a virtual terminal that always run even if your ssh disconnected.

First use `screen` command to create screen window within the same shell. It will display you bunch of info just press enter or spacebar. Than you come up with similar terminal of yours. Start your app in that terminal:

`./manage.py runworker`

now your app is running and you can detach from screen window with `ctrl+a d`.
This will return you to your real terminal. 
When you want to come back your detached screen window that is running in background just type `screen -dr` or if you have multiple detached screen windows first list all of them with `screen -ls` and than re attach the window you desire with `screen -r [number_of_window]`. When you are done you can kill screen window with `ctrl+a k` from inside the screen window.